# Read current page title with screen reader when push/pop a page

Tags: xamarin.forms, accessibility, navigationbar

I'm developing an app for blind or visually impaired people using Xamarin.Forms. I have a `NavigationPage` with the title X, and when the app starts talkback reads the title X. I have 4 pages that can be navigated to with A, B, C and D titles. I would like that when navigating through different pages, the screen reader would read the title of the page. Is it possible?

For example, if I switch on talkback on Android and I navigate through settings pages, talkback reads all page titles. I want to do something similar.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/accessibility/automation-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read current page title with screen reader when push/pop a page

You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve the feature on each platform and call the function code in the **OnAppearing** method of each page.

Check the code:

Create an interface in the shared project.

```
public interface IAccessibilityManager
{
    void sendAccessibility(string speakText);
}
```

Implement the interface in the required platform projects.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DroidAccessibilityImplement))]
namespace App19F_9.Droid
{
    public class DroidAccessibilityImplement : IAccessibilityManager
    {
        public void sendAccessibility(string speakContent)
        {
            AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AccessibilityService);
            if (manager.IsEnabled)
            {
                AccessibilityEvent _event = AccessibilityEvent.Obtain();
                _event.EventType = EventTypes.Announcement;
                _event.Text.Add(new Java.Lang.String(speakContent));
                manager.SendAccessibilityEvent(_event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resolve the platform implementations from shared code.

```
public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
    ...
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        DependencyService.Get<IAccessibilityManager>().sendAccessibility(this.Title);
    }
}
```